# Config Wizard : Farm products and patches were not detected but already installed

Tags: configuration-wizard, patching

I am facing an annoying issue with my SharePoint 2010 platform, here is the situation :

1. SharePoint 2010 Standard with Office Web Apps
2. Multi-language
3. 2 WFE

When running the configuration wizard, one of my server is in error mode :

> "Farm products and patches". The following update is missing for one server :"Microsoft Office Web Apps Front End Components".

But it is already installed. Even if I start again the setup, I have a pop up saying that this update is already installed.

I have run several PowerShell commands like `Get-SPProduct -local` or running the wizard with PowerShell without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run the Get-spprouct on both server? did you reboot the server? We had the same issues, after reboot and get-spproduct on both servers helped us.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, Get-SPProduct on both server, reboot and co, but same issue !

Comment: Any update guys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your information, it was related to a language pack that was uninstalled, and we had to delete the associated reference in the Registry